# mysql : foreign key error during table generation

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE admin_user (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE mappa (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_utente INT(11) NOT NULL,
data_creazione timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
foreign key(id_utente) references admin_user(id) on delete cascade on update no action
);
```

The second table gives me this error:
Can't create table `db`.`mappa` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

What is wrong in the key syntax mysql reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `admin_user` table `id` you assigned `UNSIGNED` value & Your reference table `id_utente` foreign key should be assign `UNSIGNED`.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE mappa (
   id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   id_utente INT(11) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
   data_creazione timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   FOREIGN KEY (id_utente) 
   REFERENCES admin_user(id) 
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an INT(11) UNSIGNED type in the admin_user table and INT(11) in the referrer. This doesn't work. Like [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says:

> The size and sign of integer types must be the same.

Make the `id_utente` column also UNSIGNED.